# how to improve sql INSERT INTO speed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?phph
$Q=mysql_query("SELECT case_number,boxes FROM master");
    while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($Q))

    {

             $s=trim($arr['case_number']);

             $noc=trim($arr['boxes']) ;

             $e=($s+$noc-1);


        for($x=$s;$s<=$e;$s++)
            {


                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO master_break (case_number) VALUES('$s')");

                    $x++;




        }

        }?>
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: I have two tables called master and master_break. master table contains fields called case_number and boxes.. I need to create master_break table using master values...
this query consumes more time and memory. how to increase execution speed

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try to do is inserting in batches. [Insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) supports something like:

```
INSERT INTO master_break (case_number) VALUES (123), (456), ...
```

Try it with increasingly higher batch sizes until you find something that suits you.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about this in the manual - particularly, the stuff about [insert....select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html), [delayed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html), [multiple row inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), and disable/enable keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into master_break(case_number) 
(select case_number from master)
```

If you need only the unique ones, add a DISTINCT:

```
   Insert into master_break(case_number) 
    (select distinct case_number from master)
```

Comment: The only sensible answer. No need to use a slow loop here. (But the brackets around the select are not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

make all your insert in one transaction speed up time significantly.

like

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION', $link); 
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i) 
{ 
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO master_break (case_number) VALUES('$s')", $link);
}
mysql_query('COMMIT', $link);
```

see in http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/doctrine-2-not-the-same-old-php-orm slide 52

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements and stuff them all into a transaction. i.e.:

```
$pdoHandler->beginTransaction();
for (whatever) {
    $query = $pdoHandler->prepare(whatever);
    $query->bindParam(whatever);
    $query->execute();
}
try {
    $pdoHandler->commit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    do whatever;
}
```

That way, you'll be safe from SQL injections too.